# Erro de passo no np.arange

Tags: numpy

Estou com um problema no arange que não retorna valores precisos.

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.2 ):
      print(i)
```

O resultado é:
0.0
0.2
0.4
0.6000000000000001
0.8
1.0
1.2000000000000002
1.4000000000000001
1.6
1.8
2.0
2.2
2.4000000000000004
2.6
2.8000000000000003
3.0
3.2
3.4000000000000004
3.6
3.8000000000000003
4.0
4.2
4.4
4.6000000000000005
4.800000000000001

Ou seja, deveria retornar 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8...mas está criando números com muitas casas decimais após a 3ª iteração.

Comment: Leia isso aqui - é importante. Muito importante.
https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o Python usa a aritmética de ponto flutuante, que não pode representar exatamente alguns números e o np.arange funciona adicionando repetidamente o valor do passo ao valor inicial, e isso leva à imprecisão no final.

Você pode contornar isso arredondando os valores com a precisão necessária (de uma casa decimal nesse caso):

```
for i in np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.2):
    print(round(i,1))
```

Ou, por conveniencia, pode criar uma função que já cria da maneira correta:

```
def arange(inicio, fim, passo):
    return passo * np.arange(inicio / passo, fim / passo)
```

Assim:

```
for i in arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.2):
      print(i)
```

Retorna os valores esperados.

Espero ter ajudado :)